# IPFire firewall under Hyper-V. How to get synthetic devices working?

Tags: linux, firewall, hyper-v, drivers

The latest version of IPFire (v2.7 core 38) uses the linux 2.6.32.15 kernel. This includes Microsoft's Hyper-V synthetic drivers. How do I get them working?

When IPFire boots, it loads the `hv_vmbus` driver automatically. That's great. I just want it to also load the network drivers and storage drivers (even just the network drivers will do!).

I can see the drivers (`hv_netvsc.ko` amongst others) stored in `/lib/modules/2.6.32.15-ipfire/kernel/drivers/staging/hv` but I just can't seem to work out where to configure the system to use them. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here
http://blogs.technet.com/b/enterprise_admin/archive/2010/03/09/linux-and-hyper-v-the-easy-way-brown-and-serve.aspx

Answer (score 2):

OK the answer I posted above doesn't quite tell which file to add them to, and the link may change at some time, so here's what I ended up doing to get it going:

add the following to /etc/sysconfig/modules

```
###Hyper-V Synthetic Drivers
hv_vmbus
hv_storvsc
hv_blkvsc
hv_netvsc
```